# Gradle: Task for deploying to appengine with testing configuration?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I have a gradle project with a very simple Google App Engine configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

// ...

appengine {
    deploy {  
        stopPreviousVersion = true 
        promote = true             
        project = 'my-awesome-project'
    }
    run {   
        port = 3000 
    }
}
```

This configures the app engine gradle tasks, e.g. `appengineDeploy`.

What I would like to do is to create another gradle task named `appengineDeployTesting` which does exactly the same thing as `appengineDeploy`, except that it uses a different `project` name (e.g. `my-awesome-project-testing`).

Ultimately, I want to end up with two tasks:

- `appengineDeploy` to deploy to the production instance
- `appengineDeployTesting` to deploy to the testing instance

How would you do this in gradle? I know how to create a task dependency, but this case requires more than just a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First option**

Well, if you only want to change the project where you are deploying you can do a simple condition check in Gradle, just before the `appengine { ... }` line, for example:

```
if (project.hasProperty('testProject')) {
    appengine.deploy.project = "my-awesome-project"
}else{
    appengine.deploy.project = "main-project"
}
```

Remember to remove the tag "project" inside the "appengine.deploy" field, so you don't overwrite the project name, for example:

```
appengine {
    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = true
        promote = true
    }
}
```

To deploy the application to your test project, you can just add the flag:

```
gradle appengineDeploy -PnewProject
```

And to deploy to the main project, just remove it:

```
gradle appengineDeploy
```

What you were asking was to create your own plugin in order to create a specific command to deploy to a specific project, you can [follow the official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) on how you can do it, however I think this solution is way simpler.

**Second option**

To avoid using flags, you can add the following code in the `build.gradle` file, after the `appengine {...}` structure:

```
task appengineDeployTesting {
        doLast{
                appengine.deploy.project = "my-awesome-project"
        }
}

appengineDeployTesting.finalizedBy appengineDeploy
```

Then running the command:

```
gradle appengineDeployTesting
```

Will first run the `appengineDeployTesting` task, and once finished will set the new project name and run the `appengineDeploy` task to deploy.

Comment: I'd like to do it without a flag, but with another gradle task instead. Flags are more error prone because they need to be assigned manually to the run configuration if you use an IDE. People tend to forget that.

Comment: @Alan47 I have edited the answer with an option that doesn't require flags :)

Comment: I tried this today, and it works perfectly! The only thing I changed in addition was that I moved the `finalizedBy appengineDeploy` into the `task` block itself. I think this makes it a little bit more concise. Does exactly what I wanted, thanks!